# Study the continuity of $f : (\Bbb R, \tau_u) → (\Bbb R, \tau_u); f=g : (\Bbb R, \tau_S) → (\Bbb R, \tau_S),\ldots$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_u$ the usual topology and $\tau_S$ be the topology on $\Bbb R$ formed by the intervals of the form $(a, b]$, their unions and the empty set. We define $f : \Bbb R → \Bbb R$ by
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+2 & \text{ if } x\le 3 \\
0 & \text{ if } x> 3
\end{cases}$$

$f : (\Bbb R, \tau_u) → (\Bbb R, \tau_u); f=g : (\Bbb R, \tau_S) → (\Bbb R, \tau_S); f=h : (\Bbb R, \tau_u) → (\Bbb R, \tau_S); f=k : (\Bbb R, \tau_S) → (\Bbb R, \tau_u)$

**Try:**

I already studied the continuity of $f$ and $h$ and both are not continuous. But I'm missing the other two, and I think those are continuous but I don't know how to prove it, any help?

Comment: What is $f(3)$ supposed to be equal to? Is it $5$ or $0$?

Comment: Moreover, if $f = g$ and $f$ is not continuous, how then can $g$ be continuous?

Comment: In addition, it appears the mappings $f, g, h, k$ differ only at the single value $3$. It would seem then that none of them is continuous.

Comment: Furthermore, not only is the mapping $f$ apparently not continuous, but it is not even a function at all.

Comment: I made a mistake writing the function, the value of $f(3)=5$. @cpiegore

Comment: At a cursory look, it seems the functions $f, g, h ,k$ are all defined by the same piecewise formula. If so, then I do not see any reason why the choice of topology should affect continuity.

Comment: Additionally, you do not appear to have any restrictions on the values $a, b$. As such, I do not see how the topologies $\tau_u$ and $\tau_S$ are different in a way that is relevant to your question.